# Program stops after cin

Tags: c++, cin

Hi there I am writing this program but I can't get it to even start to see if the other code has problems.

I have this:

```
    int main()
{
    int answer;
    int test;
    cout << "Please Enter the number to be tested: ";
    cin >> test; //Gets number to be tested
        cout << "here";
    answer = factor(test);
    cout << "The answer is:" << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

now then. It will print out the first cout, and then it gets to the cin, takes the number but then won't do anything. Won't even print the second cout. Any ideas?

I"m pretty new and haven't really done much so any extra treating me like an idiot explanations are welcomed. :D Thanks.

Comment: It's C++ not C. I retagged it.

Comment: What does "takes the number" mean? Do you get any response? Have you pressed Return or Enter to confirm the input?

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I'll keep that in mind next post.

Comment: You mean "//Gets number to be tested"? Isn't that just a comment? And I do press return.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what `factor` does. Also, add `<< endl` to your `cout` to make sure it gets flushed, in case `factor` is the culprit that makes it hang.

Comment: This program is correct and works on my computer. Your problem is probably not due to cin.

Comment: What does flushed mean? And I added it now. Factor takes the input and finds the factors then sees if it is a prime factor.

Comment: Bottom line: `cout << "here";` buffers that output but doesn't display it - follow franks advice and add endl.  Then, factor() must be in a (near-)infinite loop, or you're running UNIX/Linux and your shell prompt's returning to the left margin and overwriting your output.  Put a newline (i.e. `<< '\n'`) after answer too.

Comment: Computers often do what's called buffering.  Basically, it's inefficient to follow lengthy procedures for every tiny bit of data they're processing, so they do it in chunks.  By default, and depending on your OS, terminal environment settings etc - your cout stream may be line buffered (processed after each newline), or it may be unbuffered (processed when full or explicitly flushed using endl or flush).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there is something wrong with the factor function? An infinite loop?
Then cout << "here" << endl; (to flush the output) should at least print "here".

Comment: Yep, that got it, I'm sure theres a problem with the rest of the functions I was using the here line as a test to see where my program started having problems. Now time to go fix the rest of it since it at least will get past the input part now!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `<< endl;`is missing in your `cout` lines. That causes the output buffer not not be flushed and nothing to appear on the screen. Although that might be dependent on the platform you are running it on. It *might* work on some systems that flush the output buffer permanently.

```
int main()
{
int answer;
int test;
cout << "Please Enter the number to be tested: ";
cin >> test; //Gets number to be tested
    cout << "here" << endl;
answer = factor(test);
cout << "The answer is:" << answer << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually the factor() is blocking. Flushing the first cout would only give him the "here" output but the program will still not respond

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the program is waiting for the input at the terminal . Once you provide the input and then press "Enter"  it will automatically consider the input and the next cout statement works fine ... 
Check the below code segment ... ( nothing modified except the dummy implementation for factor, which is not the topic of discussion here )

```
enter code here
```

## include

using namespace std;

int factor(int t) {
        return t;
}

```
int main()
```

{
    int answer;
    int test;
    cout << "Please Enter the number to be tested: ";
    cin >> test; //Gets number to be tested
        cout << "here";
    answer = factor(test);
    cout << "The answer is:" << answer;
    return 0;
}

O/p is : 
$ ./a.out
Please Enter the number to be tested: 1234
hereThe answer is:1234user@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out
Please Enter the number to be tested: 1234
hereThe answer is:1234$

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results when I was hitting enter on the keypad right after my input.  If I hit return then the program runs fine.  I thought enter and return are the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

```
This is how it work "here " your screen doesnot be static by putting system("pause") you can do it ,on the other hand i have just made the function defination dummi still happen anything check there]


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int factor(int x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int answer;
    int test;
    cout << "Please Enter the number to be tested: ";
    cin >> test; //Gets number to be tested
    cout << "here";
    answer = factor(test);
    cout << "The answer is:" << answer;

    **system("pause");**


}
```

Comment: what is the problem that i am missing???its run okay and its according to the problem. . .